# Windows 10 User Environment Variable PATH updated but changes not recognized

Tags: environment-variables, path

I want to modify the User Path variable, let's say with "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3", which contains subl.exe, so I can use `subl` in a command prompt. I cannot modify the system environment path, so I have to do it via the user environment path.

Using setx I could modify the User path variable, if I type `echo %path%` it shows me that the path to subl was added to the variable, same when I go to 'Edit the user environment variables'. However, still neither `subl` nor `subl.exe` are recognized commands.

Following the second answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1107605/windows-10-system-environment-variables-dont-stick), I see that on my pc, the type of Path is "REG_SZ" instead of "REG_EXPAND_SZ", could that be the problem? If so, how can I change that type? If I right-click on the variable and select "Modify", it only gives me the name and the value, but not the type.

I already restarted my pc, also in an administrator-prompt added paths aren't recognized.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions, `echo %path%` returns something of the form `path1;path2;path3";path1;path2;path3;`, those double quotation marks are breaking it I suppose.

Comment: I assume you have closed the command prompted and reopened it after you change the variable?  **I assume you have ran the command to modify the variable in an elevated command prompt?**

Comment: Showing your existing path as seen by "echo %PATH%" from the command prompt might also help.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer, answer your own question. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do **not** change the Registry type of a system variable; that is *not* the issue. [On my PC, User Path is REG_SZ and System Path is REG_EXPAND_SZ.]

Second, is there an *invalid* entry in the path, prior to the addition for *subl*? Parsing of the Path variable stops after an invalid entry.

Third, why not [modify the PATH using the GUI](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/113/windows-10-set-path.html)? If you need to do that repeatedly, just open Regedit and export `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` and run the .reg file when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I took a closer look when echoing the variable, I noticed it looks (rather oddly) like this:

path1;path2;path3";path1;path2;path3;

I suppose the double quotation marks are breaking it.

Comment: @Pj0tr77 - Please provide us the **exact** output.  There shouldn't be any reason we should be left guessing.  We cannot diagnose the issue otherwise.

Comment: @Ramhound You're right, sorry, I'll do so if there comes a next time

Comment: Strange; entries in my user path that reference other environment variables were not expanded, and the type of my user's `PATH` key was `REG_SZ`. After using "Edit environment variables for your account" to change the order of the entries (i.e., a sort of no-op change), I found that my user's `PATH` key was now changed to `REG_SZ_EXPAND` (and the PATH entry now had its environment variable references expanded). So I'd be interested to know whether PATH entries with environment variables are being expanded on your system and/or if the control panel changes the type of the key on your system.

Comment: @SamMorris, interesting! Took a screen shot of Regedit before opening the User Environment Variable in the Windows (v. 20H2) CPL and compared it after opening each item, clicking *OK*, then clicking *OK* on the parent dialog -- and there was no change. At the start there were 3 REG_SZ values and 3 REG_EXPAND_SZ, and the same afterwards. Not sure what others might experience, this is a data sample of one user.

Comment: Strange indeed. I asked a few of my friends to check their own systems and three responded that their users' `PATH` value was `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. I wonder if you could make a new local user and then check their `HKCU\Environment` 's `PATH` value? I also wonder if any of the entries in your `REG_SZ` `PATH` value contain environment variable references (maybe the control panel only sets the type to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` if so?)

Comment: By default, `PATH` it should contain `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` so it would be interesting to see what `$env:PATH -split ";"` returns for your user account). Of course all this would be cleared up if Microsoft actually produced some £$%^& documentation!

Comment: Closest thing I've found to an authority is https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090205-00/?p=19243: "If you read a registry value and the data is tagged with the REG_EXPAND_SZ type, then it’s up to you to expand it if that’s what you want to do. The REG_EXPAND_SZ value is just part of the secret handshake between the code that wrote the data and the code that is reading it, a secret handshake which is well-understood by convention." so I am pretty sure `REG_EXPAND_SZ` is the expected/default value for user's `PATH` value, and something messed it up on my (and your) machines.

Comment: I can confirm that `Path` (and `OneDrive`) found under `HKCU:Environment` contain the old user path after having changed user account/directory. Seem like this reg item is not updated with new user account info. `Path` show `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Links;`, where xxxx is the old user name. Which is probably why it affect all the `winget` installs.