# Setting user PATH environment variable on Windows 10 has no effect

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, path

I have a bizarre problem with setting my user PATH variable. `C:\Program Files\ghcup\bin` is the path to my executable that I want to add to my user PATH.

I have tried `setx /M path "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\ghcup\bin"` using the administrator command prompt. This correctly sets the path for the administrator so when I run `echo %PATH%` from my administrator command prompt, `C:\Program Files\ghcup\bin` does show up. Everything works fine so long as I'm running the executable from my administrator command prompt.

However, the problem I have is that my user PATH is not set.
I have tried using the GUI to set my user PATH. The path appears to be set in in the GUI, but it doesn't show up when I run `echo %PATH%` from my user command prompt.

When I try to run the executable from my user command prompt, I continue to get the following error message: `'ghci' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1610111/windows-10-user-environment-variable-path-updated-but-changes-not-recognized) which tackles the same problem and I have checked for incorrect paths and that my PATH variable Registry is REG_SZ.

Comment: C:\Program Files\ghcup\bin  is a highly secured folder (so you need to be Admin).  Try using a neutral folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set environment variables from Windows Command Prompt using the `set` or `setx` command. The `set` command only sets the environment variable for the current session. The `setx` command sets it permanently, but not for the current session. If you want to set it for current as well as future sessions, use both `setx` and `set`.

here you have more details: https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/113/windows-10-set-path.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this, but unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: did you also try to set path to different  directory than secured one?

Comment: The PATH variable has been correctly set after shutting down my computer and restarting it. I thought 'current session' denoted the command prompt session, but I guess the 'current session' doesn't end until you shut down your computer.